# Multiple instances of unique variables in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a Pandas dataframe, and have a column of dependant variables (called CLASS), which consists of three classes: Y, N, and P.
However, when I run -

```
df.CLASS.unique()
```

I get -

```
array(['N', 'N ', 'P', 'Y', 'Y '], dtype=object)
```

I opened up the dataset in Excel, and tried using the filter to see how many unique variables were in the column; Excel says there are only 3.

The dataset is available [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343350334_Iraqi_Patiant_Dataset_of_Diabetes_IPDD) if it's of any benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"N with a space" and a "single N", both are different in Pandas, but **I think**, for Excel, they are the same.
You have to preprocess that data, use this:

```
df['CLASS'] = df['CLASS'].replace('N ', 'N')
df['CLASS'] = df['CLASS'].replace('Y ', 'Y')
```

`df.CLASS.unique()` You will get 3 classes after that.

```
array(['N', 'P', 'Y'], dtype=object)
```

Update: I tried running `=UNIQUE(N2:N1001)` this command to find uniques in Excel, and it has returned me 5 values. So, IDK what's wrong with your Excel.